# Collision stops all characters moving in the list

Tags: xna, collision-detection, xna-4.0

I am making a game where characters come from opposite sides of the screen and collide and attack each other then they are removed when they die. I have managed to enable the lists to stop moving and do damage when they collide but my problem is when 2 of them collide all of them stop moving.
My code for the shortswordsman collisions is:

```
private void shortMoveCollisions(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Rectangle shortRect;
        int shortSpeed = 2;
        int shortDamage = 20;
        bool collided = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < shortList.Count; i++)
        {
            List<Goblin> tempGoblinList = new List<Goblin>(goblinList);
            shortRect = new Rectangle((int)shortList[i].position.X, (int)shortList[i].position.Y, ShortSwordsman.texture.Width / 4 - 20, ShortSwordsman.texture.Height);

            foreach (Goblin goblin in tempGoblinList)
            {
                Rectangle goblinRect = new Rectangle((int)goblin.position.X, (int)goblin.position.Y, Goblin.texture.Width / 4 - 20, Goblin.texture.Height);
                if (shortRect.Intersects(goblinRect))
                {
                    collided = true;
                    shortList[i].AnimateAttack(gameTime);

                    shortTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                    if (shortTimer >= shortDelay)
                    {
                        shortTimer -= shortDelay;
                        goblin.health -= shortDamage;
                        if (goblin.health <= 0)
                        {
                            goblinList.Remove(goblin);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (shortRect.Intersects(background.badCastleRect))
            {
                collided = true;
                shortList[i].AnimateAttack(gameTime);

                shortTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                if (shortTimer >= shortDelay)
                {
                    shortTimer -= shortDelay;
                    badCastleHealth -= shortDamage;
                }
             }
            if (collided == false)
            {
                shortList[i].AnimateWalk(gameTime);

                shortList[i].position.X += shortSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my code for the goblins collisions is:

```
private void GoblinMoveCollisions(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Rectangle goblinRect;
        int goblinSpeed = 2;
        int goblinDamage = 20;
        bool collided = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < goblinList.Count; i++)
        {
            List<ShortSwordsman> tempShortList = new List<ShortSwordsman>(shortList);
            goblinRect = new Rectangle((int)goblinList[i].position.X, (int)goblinList[i].position.Y, Goblin.texture.Width / 4 - 20, Goblin.texture.Height);

            foreach (ShortSwordsman shortSwordsman in tempShortList)
            {
                Rectangle shortRect = new Rectangle((int)shortSwordsman.position.X, (int)shortSwordsman.position.Y, ShortSwordsman.texture.Width / 4 - 20, ShortSwordsman.texture.Height);
                if (goblinRect.Intersects(shortRect))
                {
                    collided = true;
                    goblinList[i].AnimateAttack(gameTime);

                    goblinAttackTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                    if (goblinAttackTimer >= goblinAttackDelay)
                    {
                        goblinAttackTimer -= goblinAttackDelay;
                        shortSwordsman.health -= goblinDamage;
                        if (shortSwordsman.health <= 0)
                        {
                            shortList.Remove(shortSwordsman);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (goblinRect.Intersects(background.goodCastleRect))
            {
                collided = true;
                goblinList[i].AnimateAttack(gameTime);

                goblinAttackTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                if (goblinAttackTimer >= goblinAttackDelay)
                {
                    goblinAttackTimer -= goblinAttackDelay;
                    goodCastleHealth -= goblinDamage;
                }
            }
            if (collided == false)
            {
                goblinList[i].AnimateWalk(gameTime);

                goblinList[i].position.X -= goblinSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collided `bool` shouldn't be a variable of those classes, as those classes seem to operate on the entire lists of all the entities. Instead the collision detection should happen on an entity by entity basis, basically: make the collided `bool` a property of goblins and swordsmen. This would mean that you'll have to check for intersections with other creatures of the same type as well, probably without an attack command.

Comment: Thanks but now i am having trouble with them colliding with themselves ive tried a few things like putting a `rectangle` into the constructors and using that `rectangle` so then all of them have a separate `rectangle` but i couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Could you show the new code? Making the rectangle an attribute of the entities seems like a good idea, because it will make it easier to match against `this.rectangle` and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using at the moment - shortswordsman and goblin are the same so i will only show one:

In the goblin class:

```
public Goblin(Vector2 position, float health, bool Collided, Rectangle goblinRect)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.health = health;
        this.Collided = Collided;
        this.goblinRect = goblinRect;
    }
```

In the game1 class:

```
void CreateGoblin()
    {
        goblinList.Add(new Goblin(new Vector2(1900, 270), 100, false, new Rectangle()));
    }
```

And then for the collisions i tried this - this includes the bit to try and stop them overlapping each other:

```
private void GoblinMoveCollisions(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        int goblinSpeed = 2;
        int goblinDamage = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < goblinList.Count; i++)
        {
            goblinList[i].Collided = false;
            goblinList[i].goblinRect = new Rectangle((int)goblinList[i].position.X, (int)goblinList[i].position.Y, Goblin.texture.Width / 4 - 20, Goblin.texture.Height);
            List<ShortSwordsman> tempShortList = new List<ShortSwordsman>(shortList);

            foreach (ShortSwordsman shortSwordsman in tempShortList)
            {
                Rectangle shortRect = new Rectangle((int)shortSwordsman.position.X, (int)shortSwordsman.position.Y, ShortSwordsman.texture.Width / 4 - 20, ShortSwordsman.texture.Height);
                if (goblinList[i].goblinRect.Intersects(shortRect))
                {
                    goblinList[i].Collided = true;
                    goblinList[i].AnimateAttack(gameTime);

                    goblinAttackTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                    if (goblinAttackTimer >= goblinAttackDelay)
                    {
                        goblinAttackTimer -= goblinAttackDelay;
                        shortSwordsman.health -= goblinDamage;
                        if (shortSwordsman.health <= 0)
                        {
                            shortList.Remove(shortSwordsman);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (goblinList[i].goblinRect.Intersects(background.goodCastleRect))
            {
                goblinList[i].Collided = true;
                goblinList[i].AnimateAttack(gameTime);

                goblinAttackTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                if (goblinAttackTimer >= goblinAttackDelay)
                {
                    goblinAttackTimer -= goblinAttackDelay;
                    goodCastleHealth -= goblinDamage;
                }
            }
            if (goblinList[i].goblinRect.Intersects(goblinList[i].goblinRect))
            {
                goblinList[i].Collided = true;
                goblinList[i].AnimateStill(gameTime);
            }
            if (goblinList[i].Collided == false)
            {
                goblinList[i].AnimateWalk(gameTime);
                goblinList[i].position.X -= goblinSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (goblinList[i].goblinRect.Intersects(goblinList[i].goblinRect))` will always be `true`, replace it with `for(int k = 0; k < goblinList.Count; k++) if(k!=i && goblinList[i].goblinRect.Intersects(goblinList[k].goblinRect)`

Comment: Thank you. Now they stop moving instead of overlapping but once they have stopped behind the one that fighting he stops as well and once they have stopped they do not start moving again.

Comment: Hmm... well, actually, if the list is ordered, from destination to spawn point sort it if it isn't) you can replace the for loop I mentioned with `for(int k=0; k<i; k++)` That should allow the intersection to be broken from the front, and only the front, as the entities will only check to see if there are allied entities ahead of them, rather than touching them.

Comment: Thank you so much this has helped a lot and I will be able to use it in the future when trying to collide two lists!